# Unexpected result when trying to filter fields in mongo db

Tags: mongodb

I have a document structured as follows:

```
{
  _id: "someid",
  games: [{
    slug: "world-of-warcraft",
    class: 'shaman'
  }, {
    slug: 'starcraft-ii',
    class: 'zerg'
  }],
  roles: {
    'starcraft-ii': ['player'],
    'world-of-warcraft': ['player']
  }
}
```

I am trying to filter it so that only `starcraft-ii` within the games array will show up for all players in the role of `player` in `starcraft-ii`. I do the following:

```
function getUsersInGame(slug) {
  return Users.find({
    'games.slug': slug,
    [`roles.${slug}`]: 'player'
  }, {
    fields: {
      'games.$': 1,
      'roles': 1
    }
  });
}
```

However, this does not match within the games array, and instead returns a 1-element array with `world-of-warcraft` instead.

What is the appropriate way to filter this array in mongo?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) in your fields, since the [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) will return the first element of the array. So your query should look like this:

```
function getUsersInGame(slug) {
   return Users.find(
    {
      '"roles.'+ slug + '"': { $in : ['player']}
    }, 
    {
      'games': {
          $elemMatch: {'slug': slug}
      },
      'roles': 1
    });
```

Please note the difference from the docs:

"The $ operator projects the array elements based on some **condition from the query statement**.

The $elemMatch projection operator takes an explicit condition argument. This **allows you to project based on a condition not in the query**..."

Comment: The docs say that both `$elemMatch` and `$` will return only the first element

Comment: alas, it did not, but I don't know why, because the docs definitely say it should

Comment: Okay, I found the problem, and your answer is _correct_ from a mongo standpoint, but Meteor in particular seems to want you to put `$elemMatch` within a `fields` object rather than just directly in the projection (like mongo would do)

Comment: I see. Then please accept my answer and ask another question providing the correct context (`meteor`).